# Output paths to all keys named "id" where the type of value is "string"

Tags: json, select, path, jq

Given a huge (15GB) deeply nested (12+ object layers) JSON file how can I find the paths to all the keys named `id` whose values are type `string`?

A massively simplified example file:

```
{
  "a": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "foo": "red"
    }
  ],
  "b": [
    {
      "id": "7",
      "bar": "orange",
      "baz": {
        "id": 13
      },
      "bax": {
        "id": "12"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Looking for a less ugly solution where I don't run out of RAM and have to punt to grep at the end (sigh). (I failed to figure out how to chain `to_entries` into this usefully. If that's even something I should be trying to do.)

Ugly solution 1:

```
$ cat huge.json | jq 'path(..|select(type=="string")) | join(".")' | grep -E '\.id"$'
"b.0.id"
"b.0.bax.id"
```

Ugly solution 2:

```
$ cat huge.json | jq --stream -c | grep -E '"id"],"'
[["b",0,"id"],"7"]
[["b",0,"bax","id"],"12"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do that.

```sh
jq --stream 'select(.[0][-1] == "id" and (.[1] | strings)) | .[0]' file
```

And by the way, your first *ugly solution* can be simplified to this:

```
jq 'path(.. .id? | strings)' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Stream the input in as you started with your second solution, but add some filtering. You do *not* want want to read the entire contents into memory. And also... UUOC.

```sh
$ jq --stream '
select(.[0][-1] == "id" and (.[1]|type) == "string")[0]
  | join(".")
' huge.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you both oguz and Jeff! Beautiful! This runs in 6.5 minutes (on my old laptop), never uses more than 21MB of RAM, and gives me exactly what I need. <3

```
$ jq --stream -c 'select(.[0][-1] == "id" and (.[1]|type) == "string")' huge.json
```